# Using Multiple Form in One HTML page,and get object of both form in angularjs

Tags: html, angularjs

My html code is

```
<div>
<div>
<form name="form 1" ng-submit="submitForm1()">
<input type="text" required name="text1">
</form>
</div
<div>
<form name="form 2" ng-submit="submitForm2()">
<input type="text" required name="text2">
</form>
</div>
</div>
```

and in my controller i am accessing the form using scope.controller looks like

```
$scope.submitFrom1 = function(){
  console.log(form1);
}

$scope.submitFrom2 = function(){
  console.log(form2);
}
```

but in result first form will give object and second form is returning undefined
I am getting why this is happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use ngModel for the fields inside each form to access data.
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModel

```
<form name="firstForm" ng-submit="submitForm1()">
    <input type="text" required name="text1" ng-model="firstForm.text1>
</form>

<form name="secondForm" ng-submit="submitForm2()">
    <input type="text" required name="text1" ng-model="secondForm.text1>
</form>
```

In controller

```
$scope.firstForm.text1 to access the data from first form individually.
$scope.secondForm.text1 to access the data from second form individually.
```

To get full form object just use.

```
$scope.firstForm;
$scope.secondForm;
```

Comment: i am getting the firstForm but secondForm getting is undefined

Answer (score 0):

Remove the spaces from the form names.

```
<!-- remove spaces from form name
<form name="form 1" ng-submit="submitForm1()">
-->
<form name="form1" ng-submit="submitForm1()">
<input type="text" required name="text1" ng-model="a">
</form>
<!-- remove spaces from form name
<form name="form 2" ng-submit="submitForm2()">
-->
<form name="form2" ng-submit="submitForm2()">
<input type="text" required name="text2" ng-model="b">
</form>
```

It was causing $parse errors.

The [DEMO on JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fb34ag9a/)